# Java Html to Pdf Renderer java.io.IOException: Stream closed and freeze

Tags: java, pdf

I have a Java renderer class which transforms an HTML document into a pdf file using flying-saucer library.

```
public static void openPdf(String renderedHtml)
    {
        /* save file inside tmp folder */
        boolean fileCorrectlySaved = false;
        File outputFile = null;

        try
        {
            /*
             * All below is to set off any xml validity checking off, otherwise parse function takes almost 1 minute!
             */
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            // parse the markup into an xml Document
            DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(stringBuilder.toString()));
            Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(renderedHtml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            CreationListener listener = new CreationListener();
            listener.parseMetaTags(doc);
            renderer.setListener(listener);
            renderer.setDocument(doc, null);

            outputFile = File.createTempFile("out_print", ".pdf");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            fileCorrectlySaved = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }
 [...]
}
```

it works and displays correctly the pdf file however it logs an error every time:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.zzRefill(Lexer.java:1634)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.yylex(Lexer.java:1865)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.next(CSSParser.java:1798)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.la(CSSParser.java:1810)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.stylesheet(CSSParser.java:159)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.parseStylesheet(CSSParser.java:89)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.getStylesheet(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.readAndParseAll(StyleReference.java:123)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.setDocumentContext(StyleReference.java:107)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:175)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:142)
    at Test.gui.renderer.Renderer.openPdf(Renderer.java:267)
```

the line from which the error is generated is the one calling

```
  renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
```

what happens next is that sometimes the whole operating system freezes for a couple of seconds (mouse moves all windows are frozen).

I tried changing the code in order to avoid the StreamClosed Exception but so far no results.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown after the computer freezing? Maybe try to increase the available memory for the VM.

Comment: Then it should not be a memory issue. Have you tried removing the null from `renderer.setDocument(doc, null);` and replacing with `renderer.setDocument(doc);` ?

Comment: You can take a look at [link](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/HowTo_PDF_metadata_from_xhtml_meta_tags)

Comment: You posted a link on how to add metadata to pdf. My code has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue and found that when the URL was running on https I needed to import the certificate into the **"jre/lib/security/cacerts"** JVM keystore.

```
keytool -import -alias <alias_name_here> -keystore ../lib/security/cacerts -file <path_to_public.cer>
```